# What's wrong with my python recursive code?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Sorry for my ugly English.
This is one of my homework.

I'm making function that finds the max integer in any list, tuple, integer..
like "`max_val((5, (1,2), [[1],[2]])) returns 5`"

When I ran my code, there was no syntax error. I ran as many various cases I can.
But the homework system told me this code was incorrect.
Anyone give me hint?

```
numList = []

def max_val(t): 
 
    if type(t) is int:
        numList.append(t)

    else:
        for i in range(len(t)):
            if t[i] is int:
                numList.append(t[i])
            else:
                max_val(t[i])

        return max(numList)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? What does t represent? Also you should un-indent your return statement so that both cases return.

Comment: t  is list or tuple or integer and it's mixed like [5, (1,2,[9,(101)]), [1],3,5,6,100,(5,7,8),[2,7]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [L3viathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64119405/3080723), the main issue with your code is that `numList` is a global variable. Here is a simple way to fix it without changing the logic of your code:

```py
def max_val(t):
  numList = []                # local variable
  max_val_helper(t, numList)  # fill numList with elements from t
  return max(numList)

def max_val_helper(t, numList):  # this function modifies its second argument and doesn't return a value
  if type(t) is int:
    numList.append(t)
  else:
    for i in range(len(t)):
      max_val_helper(t[i], numList)
```

The function `max_val_helper` is recursive and appends all numbers in the nested iterables to its argument `numList`. This function doesn't have a return value; the effect of calling it is that it modifies its argument. This kind of function is sometimes called a "procedure".

The function `max_val`, on the other hand, is a "pure" function: it returns a value without any side-effect, like modifying its argument or a global variable. It creates a local variable `numList`, and passes this local variable to `max_val_helper` which fills it with the numberss from the nested iterables.

The code suggested in [L3viathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64119405/3080723) is arguably more elegant than this one, but I think it's important to understand why your code didn't work properly and how to fix it.

It's also good practice to differentiate between functions with side-effects (like modifying an argument, modifying a global variable, or calls to `print`) and functions without side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Your code gives wrong results when called several times:

```
>>> max_val((5,4,3))
5
>>> max_val((2, 1))
5
```

That's because `numList` is a global variable that you don't "reset" between calls of your function.

You can simplify your code quite a bit, without needing that global variable:

```
def max_val(t): 
    if isinstance(t, int):
        return t  # t is the only element, so it's by definition the biggest
    else:
        # Assuming max_val works correctly for an element of t,
        # return the largest result
        return max(max_val(element) for element in t)
```